# Update multiple rows in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a table like that:

```
number
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

I want to change value in row 1 from 1 to 8, I used

```
update tableA set number=8 where number=1
```

the resulting table looks like follows:

```
number
8
2 
3 
4  
5
```

So far I tried the query below to update multiple rows,

```
   update tableA set number=8 where number=1;
   update tableA set number=10 where number=2;
   update tableA set number=11 where number=4;
```

And this works fine but is it possible to reduce it to something simpler?

Comment: Are the new values the result of an expression, maybe the result of a query or are these values arbitrary ones?

Answer (score 2):

In your query you can do something like this:

```
update tableA set number = number + 7 where number in (1,4);
update tableA set number=10 where number=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is, you can add the statement OR after the where to make multiple choices.

Like this:

> update tableA set number=8 where number=1 OR number=2;

Likewise you can use the between:

> update tableA set number=8 where number BETWEEN 1 AND 2;

Best regards.